# java prints only the first page of multipage pdf

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I've code up and running for sending Blob-Objects to a printer using javax.print. Everything works fine, except in some cases only the first page of multipage PDF-files is printed. The file looks normal when opened in acrobat and when I take the OutputStream that is used to feed the printjob and save it to another file I get and exact copy - so the stream seems to be okay. I have no idea why the following pages are dropped in some cases. here's my code:

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();                                           
aset.add(new Copies(1));                                                                                      
aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);                                                                      
aset.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED);                                                                                    
aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);                                                                               
aset.add(new JobName("Sammelausdruck", null));                                                            
ArrayList<String> fehlerDokumente = new ArrayList<String>();                                                  

//some standard print dialog                                                                                                              
PrintService printService = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 50, 50,                                               
    PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, aset), PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService(),       
    null, aset);                                                                                              
if (printService != null) {                                                                                   

        DocPrintJob docjob = printService.createPrintJob();                                                   
        aset.remove(JobName.class);                                                                           
        aset.add(new JobName(dok.getDokbezeichnung(), null));                                                 

        File file = <some PDF-file>;                                                                
        try {                                                                                                 
            FileInputStream psStream = new FileInputStream(file);                                      

            if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {                                         
                DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;                                      
                SimpleDoc doc = new SimpleDoc(psStream, psInFormat, null);                                    
                docjob.print(doc, aset);                                                                      
            }                                                                                                 

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                                                                   
        ...                                                      
        } catch (PrintException e) {                                                  
        ...                            
        }                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                         
}
```

Any ideas? I'm even interested in debug-ideas.
thank you

Edit:
In some very rare cases the printer (a professional office-printer with a touchscreen) provides an error-message that no matching paper is found for the given page-size and the pagesize shown is slightly off Din-A4 (210,2 x 295,8 or somthing like that). In this cases, if i manually tell the printer to use Din-A4, the printjob continues. I don't know if that has a complete different cause or is just another peculiarity of the same problem. I also tried to fiddle around with the MediaPrintableArea Attribute, but that didn't help either.